# Проблема с наследованием

Tags: html, css

Не могу переверстать меню так что бы не наследовались свойства для второго тега `nav` и списка внутри этого тега. При ковырянии меню появляются различные артефакты на разрешении `320x480` cо списком меню дизайн+туториалы+список-этот список вылазит список с боку, а должен с низу.

Код:

```css
/* CSS Document */

@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bree+Serif);

body {
 background: #212121;
 font-size:22px;
 line-height: 32px;
 color: #ffffff;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 word-wrap:break-word !important;
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 }

h1 {
 font-size: 60px;
 text-align: center;
 color: #FFF;
} 

h3 {
 font-size: 30px;
 line-height: 34px;
 text-align: center;
 color: #FFF;
}

h3 a {
 color: #FFF;
}

a {
 color: #FFF;
}

h1 {
 margin-top: 100px;
 text-align:center;
 font-size:60px;
 line-height: 70px;
 font-family: 'Bree Serif', 'serif';
 }

#container {
 margin: 0 auto;
 max-width: 890px;
}

p {
 text-align: center;
}

.toggle,
[id^=drop] {
 display: none;
}

/* Giving a background-color to the nav container. */
nav { 
 margin:0;
 padding: 0;
 background-color: #254441;
}

#logo {
 display: block;
 padding: 0 30px;
 float: left;
 font-size:20px;
 line-height: 60px;
}

/* Since we'll have the "ul li" "float:left"
 * we need to add a clear after the container. */

nav:after {
 content:"";
 display:table;
 clear:both;
}

/* Removing padding, margin and "list-style" from the "ul",
 * and adding "position:reltive" */
nav ul {
 float: right;
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
 list-style: none;
 position: relative;
 }
 
/* Positioning the navigation items inline */
nav ul li {
 margin: 0px;
 display:inline-block;
 float: left;
 background-color: #254441;
 }

/* Styling the links */
nav a {
 display:block;
 padding:14px 20px; 
 color:#FFF;
 font-size:17px;
 text-decoration:none;
}


nav ul li ul li:hover { background: #000000; }

/* Background color change on Hover */
nav a:hover { 
 background-color: #000000; 
}

/* Hide Dropdowns by Default
 * and giving it a position of absolute */
nav ul ul {
 display: none;
 position: absolute; 
 /* has to be the same number as the "line-height" of "nav a" */
 top: 60px; 
}
 
/* Display Dropdowns on Hover */
nav ul li:hover > ul {
 display:inherit;
}
 
/* Fisrt Tier Dropdown */
nav ul ul li {
 width:170px;
 float:none;
 display:list-item;
 position: relative;
}

/* Second, Third and more Tiers 
 * We move the 2nd and 3rd etc tier dropdowns to the left
 * by the amount of the width of the first tier.
*/
nav ul ul ul li {
 position: relative;
 top:-60px;
 /* has to be the same number as the "width" of "nav ul ul li" */ 
 left:170px; 
}

 
/* Change ' +' in order to change the Dropdown symbol */
li > a:after { content:  ' +'; }
li > a:only-child:after { content: ''; }


/* Media Queries
--------------------------------------------- */

@media all and (max-width : 768px) {

 #logo {
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  float: none;
 }

 nav {
  margin: 0;
 }

 /* Hide the navigation menu by default */
 /* Also hide the  */
 .toggle + a,
 .menu {
  display: none;
 }

 /* Stylinf the toggle lable */
 .toggle {
  display: block;
  background-color: #254441;
  padding:14px 20px; 
  color:#FFF;
  font-size:17px;
  text-decoration:none;
  border:none;
 }

 .toggle:hover {
  background-color: #000000;
 }

 /* Display Dropdown when clicked on Parent Lable */
 [id^=drop]:checked + ul {
  display: block;
 }

 /* Change menu item's width to 100% */
 nav ul li {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  }

 nav ul ul .toggle,
 nav ul ul a {
  padding: 0 40px;
 }

 nav ul ul ul a {
  padding: 0 80px;
 }

 nav a:hover,
  nav ul ul ul a {
  background-color: #000000;
 }
  
 nav ul li ul li .toggle,
 nav ul ul a,
  nav ul ul ul a{
  padding:14px 20px; 
  color:#FFF;
  font-size:17px; 
 }
  
  
 nav ul li ul li .toggle,
 nav ul ul a {
  background-color: #212121; 
 }

 /* Hide Dropdowns by Default */
 nav ul ul {
  float: none;
  position:static;
  color: #ffffff;
  /* has to be the same number as the "line-height" of "nav a" */
 }
  
 /* Hide menus on hover */
 nav ul ul li:hover > ul,
 nav ul li:hover > ul {
  display: none;
 }
  
 /* Fisrt Tier Dropdown */
 nav ul ul li {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
 }

 nav ul ul ul li {
  position: static;
  /* has to be the same number as the "width" of "nav ul ul li" */ 

 }

}

@media all and (max-width : 330px) {

 nav ul li {
  display:block;
  width: 94%;
 }

}
```

```html
        <nav>
        <div id="logo">Your Logo here</div>

        <label for="drop" class="toggle">Menu</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="drop" />
            <ul class="menu">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li>
                    <!-- First Tier Drop Down -->
                    <label for="drop-1" class="toggle">WordPress +</label>
                    <a href="#">WordPress</a>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="drop-1"/>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Themes and stuff</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Plugins</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Tutorials</a></li>
                    </ul> 

                </li>
                <li>

                <!-- First Tier Drop Down -->
                <label for="drop-2" class="toggle">Web Design +</label>
                <a href="#">Web Design</a>
                <input type="checkbox" id="drop-2"/>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Resources</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Links</a></li>
                    <li>
                       
                    <!-- Second Tier Drop Down -->        
                    <label for="drop-3" class="toggle">Tutorials +</label>
                    <a href="#">Tutorials</a>         
                    <input type="checkbox" id="drop-3"/>

                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">HTML/CSS</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">jQuery</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Other</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Graphic Design</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Inspiration</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>


        <p> A simple dropdown navigation menu made with CSS Only. Dropdowns are marked with a plus sign ( + )</p>
        <p> Resize the screen to see the look if the screen is smaller then 768px </p>
<nav>
      <ul>
        <li>Список1</li>
        <li>Список2</li>
        <li>Список3</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
```

[codePen Пример](https://codepen.io/daDast/pen/KvRqNg)

Comment: ссылки на код с примером нет... 
ну в css не прямой возможности не наследовать одним щелчком пальца, есть возможность наследовать, просто надо корректно прописать стили тому элементу, который с артефактами...

Comment: @Air ссылка видна в исходниках поста: https://codepen.io/daDast/pen/KvRqNg

Comment: она не рабочая.. не кликабельна

Comment: ну и что тебе мешает задать ему отдельный класс или ID или другой атрибут и задать ему те стили какие хочешь?